# Publishing PostGIS Data in Portal for ArcGIS Enterprise

Tags: postgis, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-portal, publishing

I have a PostGIS table with millions of points (x,y,z,time).

I have to develop a web app with the ArcGIS JavaScript API, to make some statistics like this application:
https://ycabon.github.io/presentations/2019-devsummit/Working-With-Your-Data-Using-the-ArcGIS-API-for-JavaScript-Feature-Layer/demos/4_client-side_statistics/index.html

I cannot find any sharing method in ArcGIS Pro, except to copy as layerPackage.
And, as a layerPackage in Portal fort AE, I can not find any option to create a FeatureLayer to use in my app.

Which is the best method to publish PostGIS data in Portal for ArcGIS Enterprise for using with ArcGIS JavaScript API 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register your PostGIS Db as a Data store with the ArcGIS Server. Then you can simply reference the file to create a portal item entry. See this link on how to add the data store: https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/manage-data/windows/registering-your-data-with-arcgis-server-using-manager.htm